# How to use .next() over several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the current code:

```
$("input[name='content_use']").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).closest('tr').next().show();
        $(this).closest('tr').next().next().show();
        $(this).closest('tr').next().next().next().show();
    } else{
        $(this).closest('tr').next().hide();
        $(this).closest('tr').next().next().hide();
        $(this).closest('tr').next().next().next().hide();
    }
});
```

:|

**EDIT:**

As you can see I must to use `next()` repeatedly to reach successive rows. How can I code this shorter?

---

**Solution**: [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) Thanks to @pimvdb

Comment: eh? try again...what are you trying to ask?

Comment: What's your markup? `nextUntil` may be the solution.

Comment: please. it's pretty obvious...

Comment: You can pass a selector to `next()`...

Comment: @NomikOS it's not so obvious if we are trying to figure what you want.

Comment: You didn't ask a question - so no, it isn't all that obvious.

Comment: @NomikOS just add the html markup too

Comment: OK! OK! I edited the Q. And the question is in the title. Thanks.- No need to downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) — *"Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements"*:

```
$("input[name='content_use']").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Might as well use `.toggle(bool)`.

Comment: @pimvdb Using **`$(this).closest('tr').nextAll().toggle(this.checked)`** will certainly be a better solution, provided that `show` and `hide` are the only methods in the function - Docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Seems good, but I don't want reach all siblings rows, just 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: You can rewrite using [inline if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) for shorter code

Comment: @NomikOS Then use `.nextAll().slice(0,3)` (more efficient than `:lt`!).

Comment: +1 Really `$(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,5).toggle(this.checked)` is a precious solution!!!